# Creating different operators in JaxB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, filterfunction

I'm using the OGC schemas from https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas.

I'm looking at the unmarshalled object structure from deserializing XML to the JaxB object.

I'm trying to construct a custom object to serialize to XML using JaxB.

The filter schema is seen http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/filter.xsd

I'm unmarshalling the object like so:

`JAXBElement<FilterType> filter = (JAXBElement<FilterType>) unmarshal.unmarshal(new File("Filter01.xml"));`

Now, I'm looking at the internal objects and see that I have different filter types. I want to create a filter type that is a binarylogicaloperator and initialize it with the proper data. The initialization part of this is what is confusing to me.

IE:

`BinaryLogicOpType blop = new BinaryLogicOpType();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines:

```
ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory()
BinaryLogicOpType _or = new BinaryLogicOpType();
JAXBElement<BinaryLogicOpType> root = objectFactory.createOr(_or);

BinaryComparisonOpType weightIsLessThan100 = new BinaryComparisonOpType();
_or.getOps()
  .add(objectFactory.createPropertyIsLessThan(weightIsLessThan100));

JAXBElement<String> weightValueReference = 
    objectFactory.createValueReference("weight");
LiteralType _100 = new LiteralType();
_100.getContent().add(100);
JAXBElement<LiteralType> _100Literal = objectFactory.createLiteral(_100);

weightIsLessThan100.getExpression().add(weightValueReference);
weightIsLessThan100.getExpression().add(_100Literal);
```

And so on.

Comment: This looks great. Attempting to marshal this into XML, I'm getting an integer error because missing "XMLRootElement" annotation. 

Is this normal?

        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);

Comment: I've typed it without any checks. No, It should not produce an error, try changing to string or something like that. Alternatively create an XML, unmarshal and then check what's in the unmarshalled object structure.